# JavaScript - Add span to each letter written in contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, html, css, contenteditable

I want to create script which add `<span>` to each letter of contenteditable div. For example:
If you write something in contenteditable `div`, in HTML code, you will see:

```
<div contenteditable="true">
    SomeText
</div>
```

What I have to do to see something like this:

```
<div contenteditable="true">
    <span>S</span>
    <span>o</span>
    <span>m</span>
    <span>e</span>
    <span>T</span>
    <span>e</span>
    <span>x</span>
    <span>t</span>
</div>
```

I wrote some code (using [Rangy](https://github.com/timdown/rangy)), but it doesn't work. You can see that code below, but I do not recommend it because it is to long and, as I said, doesn't work.

```js
$('#Box').keypress(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    var selLenght = getCaretCharacterOffsetWithin(document.getElementById('Box'));

    var precedingChar = "",
      sel, range, precedingRange;
    sel = rangy.getSelection();
    range = sel.getRangeAt(0).cloneRange();
    range.setStart(document.getElementById('Box'), 0);
    sel.setSingleRange(range);
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    range.setStart(document.getElementById('Box'), selLenght - 21);
    sel.setSingleRange(range);
/*
    var newElem = document.createElement('span');
    newElem.className = 'test';
    $(newElem).html(range.extractContents());
    range.insertNode(newElem);
    $('#MainBox > span:empty').remove();
*/
    rangy.getSelection().move('character', 0);
  });
});

function getCaretCharacterOffsetWithin(element) {
    var caretOffset = 0;
    if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined") {
        var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
        var preCaretRange = range.cloneRange();
        preCaretRange.selectNodeContents(element);
        preCaretRange.setEnd(range.endContainer, range.endOffset);
        caretOffset = preCaretRange.toString().length;
    } else if (typeof document.selection != "undefined" && document.selection.type != "Control") {
        var textRange = document.selection.createRange();
        var preCaretTextRange = document.body.createTextRange();
        preCaretTextRange.moveToElementText(element);
        preCaretTextRange.setEndPoint("EndToEnd", textRange);
        caretOffset = preCaretTextRange.text.length;
    }
    return caretOffset;
}
```

```css
div{
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://github.com/timdown/rangy/blob/master/lib/rangy-core.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div contenteditable="true" id="Box"></div>
```

How can I do something like that in JavaScript and/or JQuery and/or free for commercial use external library?
Thanks for help.

Comment: Do you need to this on keypress of after pressing a submit button for example ? Do you need the `contentediable` div or can you use a `textarea` ?

Comment: I need this on keypress event and in contenteditable div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## UPDATE:

Using this [Github solution](https://gist.github.com/al3x-edge/1010364) I solved the issue of chars appearing on the beginning.

Does this help you?

```js
var myDiv = document.getElementById("yourDiv");

function doJob(){
  var myDivContent = myDiv.textContent.trim();
  var myDivContentSplit = myDivContent.split("");
  myDiv.innerHTML = "";
  for(var i=0; i<myDivContentSplit.length ; i++){
    var newSpan = document.createElement('span')
    newSpan.innerHTML = myDivContentSplit[i];
    myDiv.appendChild(newSpan);
  }
  setEndOfContenteditable(myDiv);
}

myDiv.addEventListener("keyup", doJob);


function setEndOfContenteditable(contentEditableElement)
{
    var range,selection;
    if(document.createRange)//Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari, IE 9+
    {
        range = document.createRange();//Create a range (a range is a like the selection but invisible)
        range.selectNodeContents(contentEditableElement);//Select the entire contents of the element with the range
        range.collapse(false);//collapse the range to the end point. false means collapse to end rather than the start
        selection = window.getSelection();//get the selection object (allows you to change selection)
        selection.removeAllRanges();//remove any selections already made
        selection.addRange(range);//make the range you have just created the visible selection
    }
    else if(document.selection)//IE 8 and lower
    { 
        range = document.body.createTextRange();//Create a range (a range is a like the selection but invisible)
        range.moveToElementText(contentEditableElement);//Select the entire contents of the element with the range
        range.collapse(false);//collapse the range to the end point. false means collapse to end rather than the start
        range.select();//Select the range (make it the visible selection
    }
}
```

```css
div{
  border: 1px solid #999;
  padding: 10px;
}
span{
  background-color: #ea0;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true" id="yourDiv">
    SomeText
</div>
```

Comment: Good idea, but every written char are appear on the beginning of line.

Comment: Good remark which invited me to look at this interesting code on Github https://gist.github.com/al3x-edge/1010364 and updated my post.

Comment: Much better. I have got a difficult decision which answer I will use.

Comment: Note that in this case if you start writing in the middle of the text it will set the cursor explicitly at the end

Answer (score 3):

Using jQuery you can do something like the following, also note that we need some helper functions to manage the cursor position.

```js
var box = $('#Box');
var button = $('button');

box.on('input', function(e) {
  restoreCaret = saveCaretPosition(this);
  box.html(wrapLetters(box.text()));
  restoreCaret();
});

var textContent = '';
button.on('mousedown', function() {
  button.text('Hide HTML');
  textContent = box.text();
  box.text(box.html());
});
button.on('mouseup', function() {
  button.text('Show HTML');
  box.text(textContent);
  box.html(wrapLetters(textContent));
});


/* HELPERS */
function wrapLetters(textContent) {
  return textContent.split('').map(function(letter) {
    return '<span>' + letter + '</span>';
  }).join('');
}

function saveCaretPosition(context) {
  var selection = window.getSelection();
  var range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
  range.setStart(context, 0);
  var len = range.toString().length;

  return function restore() {
    var pos = getTextNodeAtPosition(context, len);
    selection.removeAllRanges();
    var range = new Range();
    range.setStart(pos.node, pos.position);
    selection.addRange(range);

  }
}

function getTextNodeAtPosition(root, index) {
  var lastNode = null;

  var treeWalker = document.createTreeWalker(root, NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT, function next(elem) {
    if (index > elem.textContent.length) {
      index -= elem.textContent.length;
      lastNode = elem;
      return NodeFilter.FILTER_REJECT
    }
    return NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT;
  });
  var c = treeWalker.nextNode();
  return {
    node: c ? c : root,
    position: c ? index : 0
  };
}
```

```css
#Box {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div contenteditable="true" id="Box"></div>

<button>Show HTML</button>
```

Comment: Thanks. I will use it too.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you need.

Set "Id" to your contenteditable div

and then write this simple script...

```
var text = document.getElementById("contenteditableDiv");
var string = "SomeText";
string.split("");
var i = 0, length = string.length;
for (i; i < length; i++) {
    text.innerHTML += "<span>" + string[i] + "</span>";
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/f85zsLdf/3/ if you need it...

Let me know if this helpful for you!