# Alternating font color within contenteditable

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hello I am trying to have my font color alternate as I type. However when I input new text, my text follows the same color and does not alternate. I was wondering why it is not alternating when I type out new letters. Many thanks for the help.

```js
$("span").each(function(index) {
  var originalText = $(this).text();
  var newText = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < originalText.length; i++) {
    if (i % 2 === 0)
      newText += "<span>" + originalText.charAt(i) + "</span>";
    else
      newText += originalText.charAt(i);
  }
  $(this).html(newText);
});
```

```css
span {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}

span>span {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div contenteditable=true>
  <span>this is just a test.</span>
  <br/>
  <span>color color color</span>
</div>
```

Comment: This question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45877256/javascript-add-span-to-each-letter-written-in-contenteditable-div can give you a great help, I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
document.getElementById("inputArea").addEventListener('input',alternateColor);
alternateColor();
function alternateColor() {
 $( "span" ).each(function( index ) {
  var originalText = $( this ).text();
  var newText = "";
  for( var i = 0; i < originalText.length; i++)
  {
      if (i % 2 === 0)
        newText += "<span>" + originalText.charAt(i) + "</span>";  
      else
        newText += originalText.charAt(i);
  }
  $( this ).html(newText);
 });
}
```

```css
span 
{
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
}

span > span
{
    color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id= "inputArea" contenteditable=true>
<span>this is just a test.</span>
<br/>
<span>color color color</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello Gokul, thanks for the help. It seems to only works for the first letter and then the text goes to the front of my row. Is there a way to fix that?